# Base de datos por defecto cuando inicia MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

acabo de crear una DB para realizar consultas en MySQL Workbench, pero cada vez que abro MySQL Workbench está abre otra DB anterior a la actual.

Uso el comando USE para volver a conectarme a la DB, pero ya está comenzando a ser un poco molesto,

¿Saben si se puede configurar de alguna forma que cada vez que abra MySQL Workbench está abra la DB que estoy usando actualmente?

Comment: Modifica el [*Default Schema*](https://www.quackit.com/pix/mysql/tutorial/default_database/mysql_default_database_1.png).

Comment: Funciono, Gracias @Sal !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias @Sal por mencionarme sobre la opción de Default Schema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]